# roulette wheel using HTML5?

Tags: html

i'm working on a roulette wheel function using HTML5. The issue that I have at the moment is that I cannot get all the numbers on the table to fit in correctly with their own colours!

it seems like half of the wheel is empty for some reason!

here is the JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/e8wfvuvh/

AND THIS IS THE CODE:

```
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/default/files/1010/source/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<input type="button" value="spin" onclick="spin();" style="float: left;" />
<canvas id="wheelcanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<script type="application/javascript">
  var colors = ["#2a8251", "#dc0927", "#414243", "#dc0927", "#2E2C75", 
                  "#dc0927", "#414243", "#dc0927", "#2E2C75", 
                  "#dc0927", "#414243", "#dc0927", "#2E2C75",
                  "#dc0927", "#414243", "#dc0927", "#2E2C75",
                  "#dc0927", "#414243", "#dc0927", "#2E2C75",
                  "#dc0927", "#414243", "#dc0927", "#2E2C75",
                  "#dc0927", "#414243", "#dc0927", "#2E2C75",
                  "#dc0927", "#414243", "#dc0927", "#2E2C75",
                  "#dc0927", "#414243", "#dc0927", "#2E2C75"];
  var restaraunts = ["0", "32", "15", "19",
                     "4", "21", "2", "25",
                     "17", "34", "6", "27",
                     "13", "36", "11", "30",
                     "8", "23", "10", "5",
                     "24", "16", "33", "20",
                     "17", "14", "31", "9",
                     "22", "18", "29", "7",
                     "28", "12", "35", "3", "26"];

  var startAngle = 0;
  var arc = Math.PI / 32;
  var spinTimeout = null;

  var spinArcStart = 10;
  var spinTime = 0;
  var spinTimeTotal = 0;

  var ctx;

  function draw() {
    drawRouletteWheel();
  }

  function drawRouletteWheel() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("wheelcanvas");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
      var outsideRadius = 200;
      var textRadius = 160;
      var insideRadius = 125;

      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);


      ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;

      ctx.font = 'bold 12px sans-serif';

      for(var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
        ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
        ctx.arc(250, 250, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.save();
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
        ctx.shadowBlur    = 0;
        ctx.shadowColor   = "rgb(220,220,220)";
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius, 250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
        ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
        var text = restaraunts[i];
        ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
        ctx.restore();
      } 

      //Arrow
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 + 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 13));
      ctx.lineTo(250 - 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
      ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }

  function spin() {
    spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
    spinTime = 0;
    spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1000;
    rotateWheel();
  }

  function rotateWheel() {
    spinTime += 30;
    if(spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
      stopRotateWheel();
      return;
    }
    var spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal);
    startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
    drawRouletteWheel();
    spinTimeout = setTimeout('rotateWheel()', 30);
  }

  function stopRotateWheel() {
    clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
    var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
    var arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
    var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.font = 'bold 30px sans-serif';
    var text = restaraunts[index]
    ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
    ctx.restore();
  }

  function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
    var ts = (t/=d)*t;
    var tc = ts*t;
    return b+c*(tc + -3*ts + 3*t);
  }

  draw();
</script>
```

I have all the Numbers and their colours (green,black, red) in my code but I don't understand why it shows the wheel in half circle and all the numbers are scrambled like that!

also, there is a dark blue colour that is shown in wheel for some numbers which I don't understand where its coming from!

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.PI is 180 degrees - so to get a full circle you have to use 2 * Math.PI

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't have any affect on it !

Comment: I've tried it with your code. Replacing var arc = Math.PI/32 with var arc = (2 * Math.PI) / 32 gives you a full circle.

Comment: Spot on... i was changing the Math.PI at the bottom of my code. Thank you very much.